# Return multiple values to a method caller

Tags: c#, return

I read the [C++ version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function) but didn't really understand it.

Can someone please explain clearly if it can be done in C#, and how?

Comment: based on answer of mentioned question, in C/C++  & before variable name mean pass by reference, use reference parameters you can pass variable to function and change it's value inside function, in C# you can do it with ref / out parameters

Answer (score 797, accepted):

In C# 7 and above, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36436255/316760).

In previous versions, you can use [.NET 4.0+'s Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

For Example:

```
public Tuple<int, int> GetMultipleValue()
{
     return Tuple.Create(1,2);
}
```

Tuples with two values have `Item1` and `Item2` as properties.

Comment: It would be very very nice if instead of Item1, Item2 and so on one could use named output values. [C# 7 possibly is going to provide that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36436255/3375713).

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ is absolutely right this is expected to be supported in the upcoming C# 7.0 using a syntax like: `public (int sum, int count) GetMultipleValues() 
{
    return (1, 2);
}` This example was taken from [our Documentation topic example on this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1936/c-sharp-7-0-features/6329/language-support-for-tuples).

Comment: How do I catch the returned tuple and access them on the caller side?

Comment: @mLstudent33 See [example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#tuples). For this example we would do something like: `(int num1, int num2) = GetMultipleValue();`

Comment: Although possible to use Tuples for that purpose, I'd advise against that. Consider creating a class so you can give a name to what you're returning, otherwise other devs will have to F12 into the method to see what's being returned there, making maintenance harder than it should be.

Answer (score 838):

Now that C# 7 has been released, you can use the new included Tuples syntax

```
(string, string, string) LookupName(long id) // tuple return type
{
    ... // retrieve first, middle and last from data storage
    return (first, middle, last); // tuple literal
}
```

which could then be used like this:

```
var names = LookupName(id);
WriteLine($"found {names.Item1} {names.Item3}.");
```

You can also provide names to your elements (so they are not "Item1", "Item2" etc). You can do it by adding a name to the signature or the return methods:

```
(string first, string middle, string last) LookupName(long id) // tuple elements have names
```

or

```
return (first: first, middle: middle, last: last); // named tuple elements in a literal
```

They can also be deconstructed, which is a pretty nice new feature:

```
(string first, string middle, string last) = LookupName(id1); // deconstructing declaration
```

Check out [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) to see more examples on what can be done :)

Comment: If you're targeting anything earlier than .NET Framework 4.7 or .NET Core 2.0, you'll need to [install a NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38383064/138757).

Comment: To get the return you can do: "var result = LookupName(5); Console.WriteLine(result.middle)".

Comment: (string,string, string) is much simplier than defining the function return type as Tuple<string,string,string> and returning a create Tuple<value1, value2, value3>

Comment: Can you use LookupName(id1) product in calling DoSomethingWtthName(string first, string last) method directly somehow? DoSomethingWithName(<take first and last from..>LookupName(id))

Answer (score 285):

You can use three different ways

**1. ref / out parameters**

**using ref:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int add = 0;
    int multiply = 0;
    Add_Multiply(a, b, ref add, ref multiply);
    Console.WriteLine(add);
    Console.WriteLine(multiply);
}

private static void Add_Multiply(int a, int b, ref int add, ref int multiply)
{
    add = a + b;
    multiply = a * b;
}
```

**using out:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int add;
    int multiply;
    Add_Multiply(a, b, out add, out multiply);
    Console.WriteLine(add);
    Console.WriteLine(multiply);
}

private static void Add_Multiply(int a, int b, out int add, out int multiply)
{
    add = a + b;
    multiply = a * b;
}
```

**2. struct / class**

**using struct:**

```
struct Result
{
    public int add;
    public int multiply;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    var result = Add_Multiply(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine(result.add);
    Console.WriteLine(result.multiply);
}

private static Result Add_Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    var result = new Result
    {
        add = a * b,
        multiply = a + b
    };
    return result;
}
```

**using class:**

```
class Result
{
    public int add;
    public int multiply;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    var result = Add_Multiply(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine(result.add);
    Console.WriteLine(result.multiply);
}

private static Result Add_Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    var result = new Result
    {
        add = a * b,
        multiply = a + b
    };
    return result;
}
```

**3. Tuple**

**Tuple class**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    var result = Add_Multiply(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Item2);
}

private static Tuple<int, int> Add_Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    var tuple = new Tuple<int, int>(a + b, a * b);
    return tuple;
}
```

**C# 7 Tuples**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    (int a_plus_b, int a_mult_b) = Add_Multiply(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine(a_plus_b);
    Console.WriteLine(a_mult_b);
}

private static (int a_plus_b, int a_mult_b) Add_Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return(a + b, a * b);
}
```

Comment: For your info, a small (irrelevant) typo: In the struct/class solutions you mixed up adding/multiplying.

Comment: I suggest putting C# 7 Tuples as the top option. It's by far the best one, IMO.

Comment: The ref / out parameters should be avoided for this purpose as they can clutter up the code. The Tuple is the best option

Comment: @Jakob isn't `out` the closest thing C# has to native multiple return? The tuple probably is the best option for readability. Personally, I'm not keen on having anonymous types or property names like `Item1` - although I guess destructuring does mitigate that. The last example, in terms of source code, definitely looks the most like multiple return in languages with that as a native feature. It's too bad there are so many options we need to choose from.

Answer (score 75):

You cannot do this in C#. What you can do is have a `out` parameter or return your own class (or struct if you want it to be immutable).

Using out parameter

```
public int GetDay(DateTime date, out string name)
{
  // ...
}
```

Using custom class (or struct)

```
public DayOfWeek GetDay(DateTime date)
{
  // ...
}

public class DayOfWeek
{
  public int Day { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: An alternative in this case is to use a struct instead of a class for the return type. If the return value is stateless and transient, struct is a better choice.

Comment: This is not possible with `async` methods. `Tuple` is the way to go. (I use `out` parameters in synchronous operations though; they are indeed useful in those cases.)

Comment: This is now possible in C# 7: (int, int) Method() { return (1, 2); }

Comment: Answer needs to be updated, it has become flat out wrong with recent versions of c#.  will change downvote to upvote if updated.

Comment: Working on a legacy code base, returning a custom class was a solid approach for me.

Answer (score 67):

In C#7 There is a new `Tuple` syntax:

```
static (string foo, int bar) GetTuple()
{
    return ("hello", 5);
}
```

You can return this as a record:

```
var result = GetTuple();
var foo = result.foo
// foo == "hello"
```

You can also use the new deconstructor syntax:

```
(string foo) = GetTuple();
// foo == "hello"
```

Be careful with serialisation however, all this is syntactic sugar - in the actual compiled code this will be a `Tuple<string, int>` (as [per the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278769/905)) with `Item1` and `Item2` instead of `foo` and `bar`. That means that serialisation (or deserialisation) will use those property names instead.

So, for serialisation declare a record class and return that instead.

Also new in C#7 is an improved syntax for `out` parameters. You can now declare the `out` inline, which is better suited in some contexts:

```
if(int.TryParse("123", out int result)) {
    // Do something with result
}
```

However, mostly you'll use this in .NET's own libraries, rather than in you own functions.

Comment: Please note that, depending on what .Net version you're targeting, you may need to install Nuget package System.ValueTuple.

Comment: i was about to answer as above ;-)

Answer (score 42):

If you mean returning multiple values, you can either return a class/struct containing the values you want to return, or use the "out" keyword on your parameters, like so:

```
public void Foo(int input, out int output1, out string output2, out string errors) {
    // set out parameters inside function
}
```

Comment: I don't think it good to use "out" or "ref"——because it can be totally substituted by a returned-value of your own class type.
you see, if using "ref", how to assign to such parameters? (It just depends on how to code inside). If in the body of the function, the author has "newed" an instance to the parameter with "ref", this means you can just pass a "nullable" value there. Otherwises not. So that's a little ambigent. And we have better ways (1. Returning your owned class, 2. Turple).

Comment: This is the only answer that will work with `ref struct`. Like for example `Span<T>`. You cannot return Span's inside a tuple.

Answer (score 38):

There is many way; but if you don't want to create a new Object or structure or something like this you can do like below  after [C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7) :

```
 (string firstName, string lastName) GetName(string myParameter)
    {
        var firstName = myParameter;
        var lastName = myParameter + " something";
        return (firstName, lastName);
    }

    void DoSomethingWithNames()
    {
        var (firstName, lastName) = GetName("myname");

    }
```

Comment: Pay Attention to the var that is used before the tuple!

Answer (score 34):

Previous poster is right. You cannot return multiple values from a C# method. However, you do have a couple of options:

- Return a structure that contains multiple members
- Return an instance of a class
- Use output parameters (using the **out** or **ref** keywords)
- Use a dictionary or key-value pair as output

The pros and cons here are often hard to figure out. If you return a structure, make sure it's small because structs are value type and passed on the stack. If you return an instance of a class, there are some design patterns here that you might want to use to avoid causing problems - members of classes can be modified because C# passes objects by reference (you don't have ByVal like you did in VB).

Finally you can use output parameters but I would limit the use of this to scenarios when you only have a couple (like 3 or less) of parameters - otherwise things get ugly and hard to maintain. Also, the use of output parameters can be an inhibitor to agility because your method signature will have to change every time you need to add something to the return value whereas returning a struct or class instance you can add members without modifying the method signature.

From an architectural standpoint I would recommend against using key-value pairs or dictionaries. I find this style of coding requires "secret knowledge" in code that consumes the method. It must know ahead of time what the keys are going to be and what the values mean and if the developer working on the internal implementation changes the way the dictionary or KVP is created, it could easily create a failure cascade throughout the entire application.

Comment: And you can also throw an `Exception` if the second value you want to return is disjunctive from the first one: like when you want to return either a kind of successful value, or a kind of unsuccessful value.

Answer (score 24):

You either return a *class instance* or use *out* parameters. Here's an example of out parameters:

```
void mymethod(out int param1, out int param2)
{
    param1 = 10;
    param2 = 20;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int i, j;
mymethod(out i, out j);
// i will be 20 and j will be 10
```

Comment: Remember, though that just because you can, doesn't mean you should do this. This is widely accepted as a bad practice in .Net in most cases.

Comment: Can you elaborate why is this a bad practise?

Comment: It's a bad practice in C/C++. The problem is "programming by side effect":

    int GetLength(char *s)
    {
        int n = 0;
        while (s[n] != '\0') n++;
        s[1] = 'X';
        return (n);
    }

    int main()
    {
        char greeting[5] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'p', '\0' };

        int len = GetLength(greeting);

        cout << len << ": " << greeting; // Output: 5: HXlp
    }

In C# you would have to write:

    int len = GetLength(ref greeting)

Which would signal a big warning flag of "Hey, greeting is not going to be the same after you call this" and greatly reduce bugs.

Answer (score 18):

> Some answers suggest using **out parameters** but I recommend
>   not using this due to **they don’t work with async methods**. See
>   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716928/how-to-write-a-async-method-with-out-parameter) for more information.

Other answers stated using Tuple, which I would recommend too but using the new feature introduced in C# 7.0.

```
(string, string, string) LookupName(long id) // tuple return type
{
    ... // retrieve first, middle and last from data storage
    return (first, middle, last); // tuple literal
}

var names = LookupName(id);
WriteLine($"found {names.Item1} {names.Item3}.");
```

Further information can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).

Answer (score 15):

```
<--Return more statements like this you can --> 

public (int,string,etc) Sample( int a, int b)  
{
    //your code;
    return (a,b);  
}
```

You can receive code like

```
(c,d,etc) = Sample( 1,2);
```

I hope it works.

Comment: This answer is perfect, does exactly what's needed. Really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

No, you can't return multiple values from a function in C# (for versions lower than C# 7), at least not in the way you can do it in Python.

However, there are a couple alternatives:

You can return an array of type object with the multiple values you want in it.

```
private object[] DoSomething()
{
    return new [] { 'value1', 'value2', 3 };
}
```

You can use `out` parameters.

```
private string DoSomething(out string outparam1, out int outparam2)
{
    outparam1 = 'value2';
    outparam2 = 3;
    return 'value1';
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways to do this.  You can use `ref` parameters:

```
int Foo(ref Bar bar) { }
```

This passes a reference to the function thereby allowing the function to modify the object in the calling code's stack.  While this is not technically a "returned" value it is a way to have a function do something similar.  In the code above the function would return an `int` and (potentially) modify `bar`.

Another similar approach is to use an `out` parameter.  An `out` parameter is identical to a `ref` parameter with an additional, compiler enforced rule.  This rule is that if you pass an `out` parameter into a function, that function is required to set its value prior to returning.  Besides that rule, an `out` parameter works just like a `ref` parameter.

The final approach (and the best in most cases) is to create a type that encapsulates both values and allow the function to return that:

```
class FooBar 
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public Bar b { get; set; }
}

FooBar Foo(Bar bar) { }
```

This final approach is simpler and easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 11):

you can try this "KeyValuePair"

```
private KeyValuePair<int, int> GetNumbers()
{
  return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 2);
}


var numbers = GetNumbers();

Console.WriteLine("Output : {0}, {1}",numbers.Key, numbers.Value);
```

**Output :**

*Output : 1, 2*

Answer (score 10):

In C# 4, you will be able to use built-in support for tuples to handle this easily.

In the meantime, there are two options.

First, you can use ref or out parameters to assign values to your parameters, which get passed back to the calling routine.

This looks like:

```
void myFunction(ref int setMe, out int youMustSetMe);
```

Second, you can wrap up your return values into a structure or class, and pass them back as members of that structure.  KeyValuePair works well for 2 - for more than 2 you would need a custom class or struct.

Answer (score 10):

When your method is **async** and you want to return multiple properties. You must do like this:

```
public async Task<(int, int)> GetMultipleValues(){
   return (1,2);
}
```

Comment: And how would this look on the caller?

Comment: @ComeIn, `var (num1, num2) = await GetMultipleValues();`

Answer (score 5):

Classes, Structures, Collections and Arrays can contain multiple values. Output and reference parameters can also be set in a function. Return multiple values is possible in dynamic and functional languages by means of tuples, but not in C#.

Answer (score 4):

Mainly two methods are there.
1. Use out/ref parameters
2. Return an Array of objects

Comment: There's also tuples, and multiple return values as a syntactic sugar for tuples.

Answer (score 4):

Here are basic `Two` methods:

**1) Use of '`out`' as parameter**
You can use 'out' for both 4.0 and minor versions too.

**Example of 'out':**

```
using System;

namespace out_parameter
{
  class Program
   {
     //Accept two input parameter and returns two out value
     public static void rect(int len, int width, out int area, out int perimeter)
      {
        area = len * width;
        perimeter = 2 * (len + width);
      }
     static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        int area, perimeter;
        // passing two parameter and getting two returning value
        Program.rect(5, 4, out area, out perimeter);
        Console.WriteLine("Area of Rectangle is {0}\t",area);
        Console.WriteLine("Perimeter of Rectangle is {0}\t", perimeter);
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

**Output:**

Area of Rectangle is 20

Perimeter of Rectangle is 18

**Note:**The `out`-keyword describes parameters whose actual variable locations are copied onto the stack of the called method, where those same locations can be rewritten. This means that the calling method will access the changed parameter.

**2) `Tuple<T>`**

**Example of Tuple:**

Returning Multiple DataType values using `Tuple<T>`

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Create four-item tuple; use var implicit type.
    var tuple = new Tuple<string, string[], int, int[]>("perl",
        new string[] { "java", "c#" },
        1,
        new int[] { 2, 3 });
    // Pass tuple as argument.
    M(tuple);
    }

    static void M(Tuple<string, string[], int, int[]> tuple)
    {
    // Evaluate the tuple's items.
    Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1);
    foreach (string value in tuple.Item2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item3);
    foreach (int value in tuple.Item4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
perl
java
c#
1
2
3
```

*NOTE:* **Use of Tuple is valid from Framework 4.0 and above**.`Tuple` type is a `class`. It will be allocated in a separate location on the managed heap in memory. Once you create the `Tuple`, you cannot change the values of its `fields`. This makes the `Tuple` more like a `struct`.

Answer (score 3):

A method taking a delegate can provide multiple values to the caller.  This borrows from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515539/5062254) and uses a little bit from [Hadas's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278769/5062254).

```
delegate void ValuesDelegate(int upVotes, int comments);
void GetMultipleValues(ValuesDelegate callback)
{
    callback(1, 2);
}
```

Callers provide a lambda (or a named function) and intellisense helps by copying the variable names from the delegate.

```
GetMultipleValues((upVotes, comments) =>
{
     Console.WriteLine($"This post has {upVotes} Up Votes and {comments} Comments.");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-return-values) article, you can use three options as posts above said.

**KeyValuePair** is quickest way.

**out** is at the second.

**Tuple** is the slowest.

Anyway, this is depend on what is the best for your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Future version of C# is going to include named tuples.
Have a look at this channel9 session for the demo
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B889

Skip to 13:00 for the tuple stuff. This will allow stuff like:

```
(int sum, int count) Tally(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
// calculate stuff here
return (0,0)
}

int resultsum = Tally(numbers).sum
```

(incomplete example from video)

Answer (score 2):

Just use in OOP manner a class like this:

```
class div
{
    public int remainder;

    public int quotient(int dividend, int divisor)
    {
        remainder = ...;
        return ...;
    }
}
```

The function member returns the quotient which most callers are primarily interested in. Additionally it stores the remainder as a data member, which is easily accessible by the caller afterwards.

This way you can have many additional "return values", very useful if you implement database or networking calls, where lots of error messages may be needed but only in case an error occurs.

I entered this solution also in the C++ question that OP is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dynamic object. I think it has better readability than Tuple.

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    var obj = GetMultipleValues();
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}

private static dynamic GetMultipleValues() {
    dynamic temp = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    temp.Id = 123;
    temp.Name = "Lorem Ipsum";
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You lose compile time type checking.

Answer (score 1):

Ways to do it:

1) KeyValuePair (Best Performance - 0.32 ns):

```
    KeyValuePair<int, int> Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4)
    {                 
         return new KeyValuePair<int,int>(p_2 - p_1, p_4-p_3);
    }
```

2) Tuple - 5.40 ns:

```
    Tuple<int, int> Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4)
    {
          return new Tuple<int, int>(p_2 - p_1, p_4-p_3);
    }
```

3) out (1.64 ns) or ref
4) Create your own custom class/struct

ns -> nanoseconds

Reference: [multiple-return-values](http://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-return-values).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an OperationResult

```
public OperationResult DoesSomething(int number1, int number2)
{
// Your Code
var returnValue1 = "return Value 1";
var returnValue2 = "return Value 2";

var operationResult = new OperationResult(returnValue1, returnValue2);
return operationResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could set your method to void and not return anything.  Instead create a public class with parameters and set them inside your method.

```
public class FooBar()
{
    public string foo { get; set; }
    public int bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then for your method try this

```
public void MyMethod(Foo foo, Bar bar)
{
    FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
    fooBar.foo = "some string";
    fooBar.bar = 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
 {
     return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't really return *multiple values*. It returns a single, collection value.

Comment: Also, why not use `yield return "value1"; yield return "value2";` as to not have to explicitly create a new `string[]`?