# Is it possible for a function to return two values?

Tags: c#

Is it possible for a function to return two values?
Array is possible if the two values are both the same type, but how do you return two different type values?

Comment: Please specify the language that your are asking of.

Comment: Excuse me I was missing the label

Comment: @lkaso - The question is tagged C#, so I'm assuming that's the language he wants.

Comment: Several answers mentioned out parameters; note that Microsoft's Framework Design Guidelines recommend avoiding using out or ref parameters in APIs. One exception is the Try-Parse Pattern, as in DateTime's bool TryParse(string, out DateTime).

Comment: The fact that you want to have one method return two different things of different types is maybe a hint that your method does not do one thing. Consider redesigning the method into two methods, each of which does one thing.

Comment: Your function can be part of a class, see my example in this other SE question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c/27059225#27059225

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Can a function return 2 separate values?  No, a function in C# can only return a single value.

It is possible though to use other concepts to return 2 values. The first that comes to mind is using a wrapping type such as a `Tuple<T1,T2>`.

```
Tuple<int,string> GetValues() {
  return Tuple.Create(42,"foo");
}
```

The `Tuple<T1,T2>` type is only available in 4.0 and higher.  If you are using an earlier version of the framework you can either create your own type or use `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`.

```
KeyValuePair<int,string> GetValues() {
  return new KeyValuePair<int,sting>(42,"foo");
}
```

Another method is to use an out parameter (I would highly recomend the tuple approach though).

```
int GetValues(out string param1) {
  param1 = "foo";
  return 42;
}
```

Comment: The road to LISP is paved with tuples!

Comment: The only drawback to tuples is that they have no semantic meaning on their own. If you're returning 2 values that are conceptually linked, encapsulating them in a class _might_ be a cleaner/more maintainable solution.  If the function is only called in one place, and the logic is simple, I'd probably use a tuple. If the function is called in many places, or the return values are used in complex algorithms, I'd say the extra code for a custom class definition is justified.

Comment: @Seth I think a struct would be more appropriate for that.

Comment: it's a shame now that we have tuples that the (int x,string y) = someFunction(); syntax is not an option (eric are you watching? :))
where someFunction returns a tuple<int,string>

Answer (score 14):

In a word, no.

But you can define a `struct` (or `class`, for that matter) for this:

```
struct TwoParameters {
    public double Parameter1 { get; private set; }
    public double Parameter2 { get; private set; }

    public TwoParameters(double param1, double param2) {
        Parameter1 = param1;
        Parameter2 = param2;
    }
}
```

This of course is way too specific to a single problem. A more flexible approach would be to define a generic `struct` like `Tuple<T1, T2>` (as JaredPar suggested):

```
struct Tuple<T1, T2> {
    public T1 Property1 { get; private set; }
    public T2 Property2 { get; private set; }

    public Tuple(T1 prop1, T2 prop2) {
        Property1 = prop1;
        Property2 = prop2;
    }
}
```

(Note that something very much like the above is actually a part of .NET in 4.0 and higher, apparently.)

Then you might have some method that looks like this:

```
public Tuple<double, int> GetPriceAndVolume() {
    double price;
    int volume;

    // calculate price and volume

    return new Tuple<double, int>(price, volume);
}
```

And code like this:

```
var priceAndVolume = GetPriceAndVolume();
double price = priceAndVolume.Property1;
int volume = priceAndVolume.Property2;
```

Answer (score 7):

It is not directly possible.  You need to return a single parameter that wraps the two parameters, or use out parameters:

```
object Method(out object secondResult)
{
    //...
```

Or:

```
KeyValuePair<object,object> Method()
{
   // ..
```

Comment: And my personal semantics for multiple return values is if it's more than one, make the function void, and put ALL the return values as "out" parameters, so you're not mixing where the "wanted" values come from.  Not NECESSARY (your way certainly works), but that's what I prefer to do.

Comment: @Kevin: I personally use a custom class or struct as necessary.  The design guidelines actually say to avoid "out" parameters, since they make the API less usable.

Answer (score 6):

All of the possible solutions miss one major point; why do you want to return two values from a method?  The way I see it, there are two possible cases; a) you are returning two values that really should be encapsulated in one object (e.g. height and width of something, so you should return an object that represents that something) or b) this is a code smell and you really need to think about why the method is returning two values (e.g. the method is really doing two things).

Answer (score 5):

with **C# 7**, you can now return a **`ValueTuple`**:

```
static (bool success, string value) GetValue(string key)
{
    if (!_dic.TryGetValue(key, out string v)) return (false, null);
    return (true, v); // this is a ValueType literal
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var (s, v) = GetValue("foo"); // (s, v) desconstructs the returned tuple
    if (s) Console.WriteLine($"foo: {v}");
}
```

`ValueTuple` is a value-type, which makes it a great choice for a return value compared with a reference-type `Tuple` - no object needs to be garbage-collected.

Also, note that you can give a name to the values returned. It is really nice.

For that reason alone I wish it was possible to declare a `ValueTuple` with only one element. Alas, it is not allowed:

```
static (string error) Foo()
{
    // ... does not work: ValueTuple must contain at least two elements
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not directly. Your options are either to return some kind of custom struct or class with multiple properties, use [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) if you simply want to return two values, or use [out parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: I'd only recommend using KeyValuePair if the two values really do represent a key/value relationship. If they are related, but neither one is a "key" to indexing the other, then I'd much rather write the code to declare a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically (at least) two options, either you make an out parameter in addition to the return value of the function, something like `T1 Function(out T2 second)` or you make your own class putting these two types together, something like a `Pair<T1,T2>`. I personally prefer the second way but it's your choice.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can return more than one value using an out parameter. See example in the TryParse method of Int32 struct. It returns bool and an integer in an out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

no but you can use an out parameter

```
 int whatitis;

string stuff = DoStuff(5, out whatitis);

 public string DoStuff(int inParam, out int outParam)
        {
            outParam = inParam + 10;
            return "donestuff";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to return more than one value from a function, unless you are returning a type that contains multiple values in it (Struct, Dictionary, etc). The only other way would be to use the "out" or "ref" keywords on the incoming parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the out parameter.

```
int maxAge;
int minAge;
public int GetMaxAgeAndMinAge(out int maxAge, out int minAge)
{
    MaxAge = 60;
    MinAge = 0;
    return 1; //irrelevant for this example since we care about the values we pass in
}
```

I really tend to stay away from this, I think that it is a code-smell. It works for quick and dirty though. A more testable and better approach would be to pass an object that represents your domain (the need to see two these two values).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
 {
     return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To return 2 values I usually use Pair class from http://blog.o-x-t.com/2007/07/16/generic-pair-net-class/.
If you need to return from method 2 values that describe the range, e.g. From/To or Min/Max, you can [use FromToRange class](https://mfreidge.wordpress.com/2016/06/11/fromtorange-generic-class/).

```
public class FromToRange<T>
    {
        public T From { get; set; }
        public T To { get; set; }

        public FromToRange()
        {
        }

        public FromToRange(T  from, T  to)
        {
            this.From = from;
            this.To = to;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string sRet = String.Format("From {0} to {1}", From, To);
            return sRet;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (this == obj) return true;
            FromToRange<T> pair = obj as FromToRange<T>;
            if (pair == null) return false;
            return Equals(From, pair.From) && Equals(To, pair.To);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (From != null ? From.GetHashCode() : 0) + 29 * (To != null ? To.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }

    }
```