# Return several types by a function

Tags: c#

I have a function and must return a string and a table of int.

In the following example,

```
private XXXX MyFunc()
{
      string st;
      int[,] table;
      ...
      return YYYY
}
```

If I want to return **st** and **table**, what type do I have to put in XXXX and YYYY ?

Comment: Either create a custom class and return it or use `Tuple` or use C# 7 anonymous return types.

Comment: Well, you could use a `Tuple<string, int[,]>` or a `ValueTuple<string, int[,]>` or a custom type, or use an out parameter. Lots of options.

Comment: Did you even attempt to Google? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570452/how-to-return-2-value-in-c-sharp-method) the first result, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c) the second one...

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom type which contains your properties.

```
struct myData
{
    string st;
    int[,] table;
}

private myData MyFunc()
{
    myData data = new myData()
    {
        st = ...,
        table = ...
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates to this question, your answer is of much lower quality than those questions already answered.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto so close as duplicate. My answer has some errors?