# Method should return multiple values

Tags: c#

Hii

I have method in C#, I have to return multiple values from that method with out using collections like arrays. Is there any reliable way ?

Comment: Can you please expand on "multiple values"? Is it a constant number of your return values? Are they linked logically? What to they represent? Are they in the same type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return multiple values from a function in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you could use:

- a custom class/struct/type, containing all your values
- `out` parameters

I.e.:

```
class MyValues
{
    public string Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 {get; set; }
}

public MyValues ReturnMyValues();
```

or

```
public void ReturnMyValues(out string Val1, out int Val2);
```

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the `out` keyword:

```
public void ReturnManyInts(out int int1, out int int2, out int int3)
{
    int1 = 10;
    int2 = 20;
    int3 = 30;
}
```

then call it like this:

```
int i1, i2, i3;
ReturnManyInts(out i1, out i2, out i3);

Console.WriteLine(i1);
Console.WriteLine(i2);
Console.WriteLine(i3);
```

which outputs:

```
10
20
30
```

EDIT:

I'm seeing that a lot of posts are suggesting to create your own class for this. This is not necessary as .net provides you with a class to do what they are saying already. The `Tuple` class.

```
public Tuple<int, string, char> ReturnMany()
{
    return new Tuple<int, string, char>(1, "some string", 'B');
}
```

then you can retrieve it like so:

```
var myTuple = ReturnMany();
myTuple.Item1 ...
myTuple.Item2 ...
```

there are generic overloads so you can have up to 8 unique types in your tuple.

Comment: Also, the `Tuple.Create` method can infer the types: `return Tuple.Create(1, "some string", 'B');`

Comment: Note that Tuple is a new feature of .NET 4.0, which Jibu may not (yet) have.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can use one of the [generic Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386941%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) classes to return multiple values from a method call. The static [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class provides methods to create Tuple objects. So you do not have to define your own return type for the method.

```
public Tuple<string,int> Execute()
{
  return new Tuple<string,int>("Hello World", 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes could create a new type that will contain multiple properties and then return this type:

```
public MyType MyMethod() 
{
    return new MyType
    {
        Prop1 = "foo",
        Prop2 = "bar"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why should  using 'out' being an unreliable way? (Or did you make a typo and meant without?)

There are several methods:

- Return a object which holds multiple
  values (struct/class etc)
- [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A Descriptor class, or structure. You must put it somewhere as it's logical that a method must return only one value. Alternatively you can use out or ref, but i would go returning a class.

Btw what's holding you not to use collections?.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Method Name(out string stringValue, out int intValue)
{
    ///
          Method goes here
    ///

    return intVaraible
}
```

here you will get 3 return Values
1. stringValue
2. intValue
3. intVariable