# Returning 2 values from a property of a class

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I return multiple values from a function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Imagine we have a property which gets a value like `10-1685` , i would like to add another property inside a class that returns these two values as separate values.How can i achieve that?

```
    public string UserName { get; set; }



    public string UserNameSeparated
    {
        get { Username.Split('-');
        }
        set
        {
            ...What do do here??
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not create a class or struct with 2 properties on it to represent your data?

Comment: Because i get the data from a database and the values are stored as X-Y and i have to assign them to classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change return type of property to array of strings:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }

public string[] UserNameSeparated
{
    get { Username.Split('-'); }
    set
    {
        UserName = String.Join("-", value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foo.UserName = "10-1685";
string[] names = foo.UserNameSeparated;
// names[0] = "10";
// names[1] = "1685";
foo.UserNameSeparated = new string[] { "15", "42" };
// foo.UserName = "15-42"
```

BUT consider to have properties for both parts of name. You will be able to calculate full name at any time, and you will deal with **nice named properties** instead of tuples or array indexes (support hell):

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }

public string UserName
{
    get { return String.Format("{0}-{1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    set 
    {
        // check if value format valid
        var names = value.Split('-');
        FirstName = names[0];
        LastName = names[1];
    }
}
```

Just compare (you can give more descriptive names, which describe your data better):

```
foo.FirstName
foo.LastName
```

With:

```
foo.UserNameSeparated.Item1
foo.UserNameSeparated.Item2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Tuple.

The question has been answered before here: [How can I return multiple values from a function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something obvious here but... why would you want to do that rather than just create a class or struct with two properties on it?

Comment: @BrandonMoore agree. Never used tuples in my code. Extremely non-descriptive data type. It takes about 10 seconds to create class with two properties.

Comment: Yes, a class with two properties is another viable solution, as seen in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

On the post Jamie referenced, there is a reference to a post that one was based on: [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

The 'popular' answer there was to use a touple.  However, you should note Bill K, Fred Larson, and Jonathan Leffler's answers which all point out the better way to achieve this is to use a class or struct.

Also look at how Microsoft structures their own code in the .net framework.  I have never once seen them use a touple as a return value for anything.  I think that's a pretty good sign in itself as to which practice is better.