# how to create array of sql data column for highchart?

Tags: c#, sql, highcharts

my c# code for data is:

```
   table T1
       Column1          Column2
    -------------     ---------------
    SingularData1      TotalDta1
    SingularData2      TotalDta2
    SingularData3      TotalDta3
    SingularData4      TotalDta4
```

how to pass data to like this feature?:

```
['SingularData1',TotalData1],['SingularData2',TotalData2],['SingularData3',TotalData3],...
```

how to resolve?
please help.

Comment: After parsing series line, how it looks like? Have you any errors in the console?

Comment: As a side note, if you want to return multiple arguments from a C# method, use a Tuple (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c), don't concatenate and then split.