# C# return bool from double[] method

Tags: c#

How can return a bool from this double array method?

```
public static double[] GetUIPosition(string name)
    {
        if (FastUICheck.FastUICheckVisible(name, 0) == true)
        {
            UIControl control = new UIControl(Engine.Current.Memory, Engine.Current.ObjectManager.x984_UI.x0000_Controls.x10_Map[name].Value.Address);
            double[] point = new double[4];
            point[0] = control.x4D8_UIRect.Left;
            point[1] = control.x4D8_UIRect.Top;
            point[2] = control.x4D8_UIRect.Right;
            point[3] = control.x4D8_UIRect.Bottom;

            return point;

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
   }
```

So basically i am checking if a control exists in memory and is visible and if yes then i want to get it's rect.
So if yes i return an array with the 4 points else i want to return false.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `bool` is not castable to `dobule[]`.

However, you can just return `null` and check for that as your "false" value.

You could also take the `TryParse` approach and return a `bool`, with the `double[]` as an `out` parameter. The signature would be:

```
public static bool GetUIPosition(string name, out double[] position)
```

Your code returning null:

```
public static double[] GetUIPosition(string name)
{
    if (FastUICheck.FastUICheckVisible(name, 0) == true)
    {
       UIControl control = new UIControl(Engine.Current.Memory, Engine.Current.ObjectManager.x984_UI.x0000_Controls.x10_Map[name].Value.Address);
       double[] point = new double[4];
       point[0] = control.x4D8_UIRect.Left;
       point[1] = control.x4D8_UIRect.Top;
       point[2] = control.x4D8_UIRect.Right;
       point[3] = control.x4D8_UIRect.Bottom;

       return point;  
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

A similar question with helpful answers: 
[How can I return multiple values from a function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c)

Comment: ... or to save from further comparison to `null` hell one could throw an exception

Comment: @zerkms, true, but I would only throw an exception if you would expect that the condition would *never* return false under normal operating conditions.

Comment: it depends. If you're invoking `GetUIPosition` for something that doesn't exist it is no different from getting file attributes for the file that doesn't exist as well (and that does throw an IO exception)

Comment: or you could do it like the `TryParse` pattern.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I had that in my answer... perhaps it needs to be more obvious

Comment: @zerkms A better example more similar to the OP's situation would be [Dictionary's indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throwing a `KeyNotFoundException` when you try to retrieve a item that does not exist.

Comment: return null will throw me an error here:
var Point = GetUIPos.GetUIPosition(name);
while (Point[0] == 0 && Point[1] == 0)

Comment: @ileandros: that's correct. Hence you need to check if the result is not `null`. PS: also think of introducing (reusing) a separate type that represents a bounding box instead of this ugly array

Comment: @ileandros, its the same check you would have needed to make if the `bool` code was compilable, you just have to make it against `null` instead of `false`.

Comment: Something like this would fix it i guess: if(Point != null){}
I didn't understand your second part though

Comment: @ileandros: the second part explanation: use a class to return the bounding box, not an array of doubles. Like this structure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx PS: I'm not telling you to use this exact structure, it's just an example

Comment: +1. Consider adding link to popular question on the topic too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c (not exact duplicate, but covers many options).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, exactly. Didn't think that way.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, added the link. Thanks for finding it!