# Return 2 values from a function?

Tags: c#

I have an object that represents a scheduled payment. My database has a list of these payments, but I have one instance of a payment.

I need to write a method that gets the next payment after the one I have, as well as the previous date of the previous payment.

I'd like to write a method that return the two dates. But the return type of '`DateTime`' only allows for one. I could return a `List<DateTime>` but that seems strange and ma be ambiguous. Which is the previous and which is the next?

I can also create a DTO object that has:

```
DateTime previousPayment {get; set;}
DateTime nextPayment {get; set;}
```

`Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>` might be another options, but it too is ambiguous. Unless I can name the properties of it?

But - is there a better way to allow for a method to return two dates? Anonymous types or something?

Comment: For multiple return you can user class object or generic list or array

Comment: Also look at this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/748062/2557263

Answer (score 3):

Use the "ref" modifier. (You may use "out" instead if you do not need to read the variable before it is assigned)

```
public void GetNextPayment(ref DateTime previousPayment, ref DateTime nextPayment){
    // do stuff here
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime previousPayment = DateTime.Now(); //Example
DateTime nextPayment = DateTime.Now(); // example
GetNextPayment(ref previousPayment, ref nextPayment); // Forgot to add "ref" when calling it
```

previousPayment and nextPayment will be modified in the function and maintain the value.

**Update with Dictionary**

As Anik mentioned, it might be better to use a Dictionary;

```
public Dictionary<string,DateTime> GetNextPayment(DateTime previousPayment, DateTime nextPayment){
    // modify payments
    Dictionary<string,DateTime> myDict = new Dictionary(string, DateTime);
    myDict.Add("PreviousPayment", [date]);
    myDict.Add("NextPayment", [date]);
    return myDict;
}
```

**Use Class**

Ilya. N. mentioned to use a class. I would have to agree with this if you're going to have lots of payment objects going to be used more than once. But I firmly believe it's better to give you all the tools available at your disposal because you never know when you might want to use out parameters or Dictionaries.

```
public class Payment {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime previousPayment {get;set;}
    public DateTime nextPayment {get;set;}

    public GetNextPayment(){
        // code to get the next payment
        this.previousPayment = //whatever
        this.nextPayment = //whatever
    }
}
```

If you only have ONE payment you are going to be using, like ever. (good to future proof with a class), then you might use a method or dictionary.

Comment: right, out parameters can really be thought of as pass by reference. C++ ftw!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply return a class?

```
public class DateCombo {
DateTime PreviousPayment {get; set;}
DateTime NextPayment {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: That was what I mentioned in my answer. Might be the only clean way.

Comment: Although I still prefer the class, Dictionary can be used as well.

Comment: I like this better than either the Tuple<T, T> answers or the `out` answers. Maybe I'm just prejudiced against out, but I find `out` appears so infrequently within the C# built-ins that it doesn't fit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two options you listed, there are two more:

1. Return a `Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>`
2. Use `out` parameters

Comment: Yeah, I just added the Tuple... I'm maybe thing 'out' is the way to go, as they're named.

Comment: Bur remeber - do not use `Tuple` for public interface - rather for internal/privte.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime previousPayment =new DateTime();
        DateTime nextPayment=new DateTime();
        getdate(ref previousPayment, ref nextPayment);
    }
    public void getdate(ref  DateTime previousPayment, ref DateTime nextPayment)
    {
        previousPayment = System.DateTime.Now;
        nextPayment = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

    }
```