# returning more than one variable by function in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Today I faced one question that which are the possible ways to 
return more than one values in function in C#

1 is returning object 
but what are other possible ways of doing it

Regards

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-c

Comment: You are either returning a value/struct or a reference. Theoretically you cannot return more, but you can instruct the method to assign a value by reference with the `ref` or `out` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You can use output parameters:

```
public void Foo(out int bar, out string goo)
{
    bar = 1;
    goo = "moo";
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int a;
string b;
Foo(out a, out b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Tuple to return more than one value. Keep in mind, they can get out of hand pretty quick.

```
public Tuple<string, int> Foo()
{
     return Tuple.Create("Bar",1);
}
```

Tupples can be spun up with multiple values.

```
Tuple<int,string,int,int,string>
```

They can get messy quick :)

Good luck

Comment: _They can get messy quick_ Yeah, Tuples should be deleted from existence. ;)

Comment: @Silvermind No kidding. I hate em.