# Method with Multiple Return Types

Tags: c#, generics, methods, return

I've looked through many questions that are similar to this, but none of them really touched on what I precisely want to do. What I am trying to do is read from an external source a list of variables that also include their data type into a string array:

Example:

```
ID/Key      Type    Value/Data; 
varName1    bool    true;
varName2    string  str;
varName3    int     5;
```

I then store these are objects into a dictionary as objects containing several strings, with the ID also serving as the key.

What I want to do is now create a method that uses a switch statement that casts the string into the correct datatype, and returns it without having to specify anything in the method call. The function should look something like this:

```
public ??? Method(string key)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(ID))
    {
        Var temp = dictionary[ID];

        switch (temp.Type)
        {
            case "bool":
                return Convert.ToBoolean(temp.Value);

            case "int"
                return Convert.ToInt(temp.Value);

            case "string"
                return temp.Value;
        }
    }

    return "NULL"; 
}
```

The method call should look something like this:

```
int x = Method(string key);
string word = Method(string key);
bool isTrue = Method(string key);
```

Maybe I've missed something, but I have yet to find something that really does something quite like this. Any and all thoughts about this are welcome as well.

Comment: Sorry, no such thing in C#.  A method has a fixed return type.  You could use `object` as your return type, but you'd have to cast.

Comment: You'd have to make the method generic for that to work.  And it would end up looking like `string word = Method<string>(key)` when you used it.  Also you'd have to do `bool?` and `int?` since you want to return `null` when the key isn't found.

Comment: If your values were stored as `Object`, you could do `(T)value`. What stopping you from `string word = (string)Method(string key);`, given, method returns `object`

Comment: How about `dynamic`?

Comment: What are you going to do with the return value of the method?

Comment: I really think, you need `public IKnowHowToconvertData Method<T>(string key)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return multiple values to a method caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/return-multiple-values-to-a-method-caller)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update

I believe a lot of people are arriving at this question because they're looking for ways to return multiple values generally, not necessarily for the purposes given in the original question. If this is what you want, there are a few options to choose from.

If the combination of your returned types represents a concept that may be useful outside of your method call, consider creating a type to represent that concept. C#'s `record`s provide a nice, concise way to do that:

```
public record ExtractedValue(bool? BooleanValue, string? StringValue, int? IntValue);

public ExtractedValue Method(string key)
{
   ...
}
```

If this is the only place these values will appear together, and it's not really worth coming up with a named type to represent the values, you can also use a Value Tuple. Just be aware that there are some behavioral implications that might bite you if you plan to use the type for things like serialization.

```
public (bool? BooleanValue, string? StringValue, int? IntValue) Method(string key)
{
   ...
}
```

### Original Answer

The compiler has no way to distinguish between the three method calls you've provided, because they all look like `Method(key);`

One option is to return an `object` and then expect the consuming code to cast it to what they want:

```
public object Method(string key)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        var temp = dictionary[key];

        switch (temp.Type)
        {
            case "bool":
                return Convert.ToBoolean(temp.Value);

            case "int"
                return Convert.ToInt(temp.Value);

            case "string"
                return temp.Value;
        }
    }

    return "NULL"; 
}

...

int x = (int) Method(key);
string word = (string) Method(key);
bool isTrue = (bool) Method(key);
```

You could also use the `dynamic` keyword to make the cast implicit:

```
public dynamic Method(string key)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        var temp = dictionary[key];

        switch (temp.Type)
        {
            case "bool":
                return Convert.ToBoolean(temp.Value);

            case "int"
                return Convert.ToInt(temp.Value);

            case "string"
                return temp.Value;
        }
    }

    return "NULL"; 
}

...

int x = Method(key);
string word = Method(key);
bool isTrue = Method(key);
```

However, `dynamic` is a very powerful concept, and it's easy for it to get out of hand, so you have to be really careful with that.

It seems to me that you're expecting your calling code to know which type of object it's expecting to get for each key. It seems like maybe the best approach is to just let the user supply that information:

```
public T Method<T>(string key)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(dictionary[key].Value, typeof(T));
    return default(T);
}

...

int x = Method<int>(key);
string word = Method<string>(key);
bool isTrue = Method<bool>(key);
```

That way, there's no need to track the Type value in your dictionary objects in the first place.

Comment: I realize that the OP used `boolean`, but in C# it's `bool` or `Boolean`.

Comment: Likewise from OP, `Var` is invalid in C#, should be `var`.

Comment: Var was the name of the class I was using to store what I had read from the file, and I was loosely going from memory on the whole bool/boolean/Boolean thing.

Comment: The dynamic keyword worked, but I just remembered I'm limited to the .3.5 framework, whereas dynamic is 4.0 only.

Comment: @FreeRadical: Well, I gave you three separate options, and only one of them uses dynamic, so let me know if there's a reason that the others won't work for you. And, btw, it's a really bad idea to name a class `Var`.

Answer (score 24):

In C# 7 you have the option to return multiple values from a method like this:

```
public (string SomeString, int SomeInt) DoSomething() { ... }
```

You can get the values like this:

```
var result = DoSomething();
Console.WriteLine(result.SomeString);
Console.WriteLine(result.SomeInt.ToString());
```

Or

```
(var someString, var someInt) = DoSomething();
Console.WriteLine(someString);
Console.WriteLine(someInt.ToString());
```

This works below the surface with a Tuple and you are not restricted to only 2 values. I don't know how many you can return but I suggest when you need to return that many values, create a class.
More info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Answer (score -1):

The return type of a function must be typed. As with any other variable or operation, any type that inherits from the specified type is a valid return value (which is why object allows anything as a value).

Personally i dont think it is useful to make one method with multiple return types but if you really want to have one method with multiple return types, you could use the [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd264741.aspx) type in .NET 4.0:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = Method("varName3");
        string word = Method("varName2");
        bool isTrue = Method("varName1");
    }

    private static dynamic Method(string key)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Type, object>>()
        {
            { "varName1", new KeyValuePair<Type, object>(typeof(bool), false) },
            { "varName2", new KeyValuePair<Type, object>(typeof(string), "str") },
            { "varName3", new KeyValuePair<Type, object>(typeof(int), 5) },
        };

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return dictionary[key].Value;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Helped wonderfully, but I'm unfortunately limited to the 3.5 framework. Background: This is a tool for people who use Unity.

Comment: If you are limited to .NET 3.5 i would try to make the method generic:
int x = Method<int>("varName3");

Please have a look at StriplingWarrior's answer.

Comment: Love how C# lets things be both static and dynamic.