# How to cast type object to type datatable

Tags: c#

I have got this object that I am using to handle all of my sql queries by returning them as objects. Here in the method listed below I can pass 3 arguments, the sql query, the type of data I would like returned and whether the sql is a query or nonquery

it returns a datatable but it gets returned as an object. So I am curious if there is a simple way once that has been returned to convert it into a datatable.

I was able to successfuly convert the list to an Ilist and then back to a list but this doesnt seem to have any possible ways of casting from object to datatable.

any help is greatly appreciated and if I didnt include something feel free to let me know.

Comment: You need to post a complete code sample. Also using strings to determine logic flow is not recommended. Try using an enum.

Comment: The same way you cast anything else: `(DataTable)myObject`.  But casting this way is not a good solution to your problem.  Try using a [generic return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the return type of a method generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798681/method-with-multiple-return-types). You can't do anything like this in C# unfortunately, but there are workarounds.

When calling the method, try:

```
DataTable newDT = (DataTable)QuerySql();
```

to cast the object when calling it.

Another thing you can try is creating the same method for each return type. For example:

```
private DataTable DTQuerySql(string QueryString, string QueryType = "select")
{
    return (DataTable)QuerySql(QueryString, "datatable", QueryType)
}
```