# Can I return more than one value from a method without creating a class for the return type or OUT params?

Tags: c#

If I have a method like this:

```
private void RunExecute()
{
    var rc1 = doStuff(2);
    var rc2 = doStuff(1);
}
```

Is there any way that I can return both rc1 and rc2 instead of the void without creating a special class and using that as the return type and without declaring rc1 and rc2 as out parameters?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Comment: Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36436255/193634

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Tuples

```
private (T,T) RunExecute()
{
    var rc1 = doStuff(2);
    var rc2 = doStuff(1);
    return (rc1,rc2)
}
```

Where T is type returned by doStuff

For example, if doStuff return int,

```
private (int,int) RunExecute()
```

To call the method and use the results, you can make use of the syntax

```
var (p1,p2) = RunExecute();
```

An alternative approach using Tuples is naming the Tuple elements. For example, during declaration.

```
private (int returnValue1,int returnValue2) RunExecute()
```

and calling it.

```
var result  = RunExecute();
Console.WriteLine(result.returnValue1);
Console.WriteLine(result.returnValue2);
```

PS: If you are using C# <7.0, you would have to limit yourself to following syntax.

```
private Tuple<int, int> RunExecute()
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how I would call and use RunExecute. Thanks

Comment: @Alan2 I have updated the answer with Method call and how to fetch the result. Kindly check