# Is there a way I can return more than one integer from a method?

Tags: c#

I have a method like this:

```
private double GetHeight()
{
    return 2;
}
```

But I would like to be able to return two different numbers for example 2 and 3. Is there any way that I can do this in C#?

Comment: return array if you need more values

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278769/8194995) probably is exactly what you need

Comment: for clarity: does your method always return the *same number* of return values (each with specific semantic meaning) - or is the number of return values *dynamic*, i.e. sometimes it'll be 1 (or maybe even zero), and other times it might be 20? It matters a lot. For the fixed number scenario: any of the tuple-ish answers are good; for the dynamic scenario: the array/list approaches are good.

Comment: How does this question have so many upvotes? The question lacks a significant amount of effort and a simple search on the internet would've provided the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples?view=netframework-4.7.2) / *Named Tuple* (available in C# 7.0). The advantage is it's the most succinct, it's immutable, and it's easy to construct.

> The ValueTuple struct has fields named Item1, Item2, Item3, and so on,
> similar to the properties defined in the existing Tuple types.
>
> However, when you initialize a tuple, you can use new language
> features that give better names to each field. Doing so creates a
> named tuple. Named tuples still have elements named Item1, Item2,
> Item3 and so on. But they also have synonyms for any of those elements
> that you have named. You create a named tuple by specifying the names
> for each element.

```
private (double first, double second) GetHeight()
{
   return (1,2);
}

...

var result = ViaNamedValueTuple();
Console.WriteLine($"{result.first}, {result.second}");

var (first, second) = ViaNamedValueTuple();
Console.WriteLine($"{first}, {second}");
```

**Classic Tuple**

[C# tuple type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples)

> The .NET Framework already has generic Tuple classes. These classes,
> however, had two major limitations. For one, the Tuple classes named
> their properties Item1, Item2, and so on. Those names carry no
> semantic information. Using these Tuple types does not enable
> communicating the meaning of each of the properties. The new language
> features enable you to declare and use semantically meaningful names
> for the elements in a tuple.

```
public Tuple<int, int> ViaClassicTuple()
{
   return new Tuple<int, int>(1,2);
}

...

var tuple = ViaClassicTuple();
Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.Item1}, {tuple.Item2}");
```

**Classic struct**

[struct (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct)

> A struct type is a value type that is typically used to encapsulate
> small groups of related variables, such as the coordinates of a
> rectangle or the characteristics of an item in an inventory.

```
public struct ClassicStruct
{
   public int First { get; set; }
   public int Second { get; set; }
   public ClassicStruct(int first, int second)
   {
      First = first;
      Second = second;
   }
}

...

public ClassicStruct ViaClassicStruct()
{
   return new ClassicStruct(1, 2);
}

... 

var classicStruct = ViaClassicStruct();
Console.WriteLine($"{classicStruct.First}, {classicStruct.Second}");
```

**Readonly struct**

[readonly (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly#readonly-struct-example)

> The readonly modifier on a struct definition declares that the struct
> is immutable. Every instance field of the struct must be marked
> readonly, as shown in the following example:

```
public readonly struct ReadonlyStruct
{
   public int First { get; }
   public int Second { get; }
   public ReadonlyStruct(int first, int second)
   {
      First = first;
      Second = second;
   }
}

...

public ReadonlyStruct ViaReadonlyStruct()
{
   return new ReadonlyStruct(1, 2);
}

...


var readonlyStruct = ViaReadonlyStruct();
Console.WriteLine($"{readonlyStruct.First}, {readonlyStruct.Second}");
```

**Simple Class**

[Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

> A type that is defined as a class is a reference type. At run time,
> when you declare a variable of a reference type, the variable contains
> the value null until you explicitly create an instance of the class by
> using the new operator, or assign it an object of a compatible type
> that may have been created elsewhere

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public int First { get; set; }
   public int Second { get; set; }
   public SomeClass(int first, int second)
   {
      First = first;
      Second = second;
   }
}

...

public SomeClass ViaSomeClass()
{
   return new SomeClass(1, 2);
}

...


var someClass = ViaSomeClass();
Console.WriteLine($"{someClass.First}, {someClass.Second}");
```

**Out parameters**

[out parameter modifier (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

> The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. It makes
> the formal parameter an alias for the argument, which must be a
> variable. In other words, any operation on the parameter is made on
> the argument. It is like the ref keyword, except that ref requires
> that the variable be initialized before it is passed. It is also like
> the in keyword, except that in does not allow the called method to
> modify the argument value. To use an out parameter, both the method
> definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword.

```
public bool ViaOutParams(out int first, out int second)
{
   first = 1;
   second = 2;
   return someCondition;
}

...

if(ViaOutParams(out var firstInt, out var secondInt))
   Console.WriteLine($"{firstInt}, {secondInt}");
```

**Out Value Tuple**

```
public bool ViaOutTuple(out (int first,int second) output)
{
   output = (1, 2);
   return someCondition;
}

...

if (ViaOutTuple(out var output))
   Console.WriteLine($"{output.first}, {output.second}");
```

Comment: Note: Available in C# 7.0 +.

Comment: Perhaps a struct would be more appropriate than a class, if the intention is to keep value passing.

Answer (score 22):

Multiple ways:

1. `out` parameters:

   ```cs
   private double GetHeight(out int anotherValue)
   {
       anotherValue = 42;
       return 2;
   }
   ```
2. value-tuples:

   ```cs
   private (double height, int anotherValue) GetHeight()
   {
       return (42, 2);
   }
   ```

   (warning: value-tuples have known problems if used in .NET Standard libraries, as the assembly bindings from .NET Standard to .NET Framework are ... kinda fubar)
3. custom return types:

   ```cs
   private Something GetHeight()
   {
       return new Something(42, 2);
   }
   ```

   (to avoid allocations, you may wish to define `Something` as a `readonly struct` in this scenario)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use **Tuple**:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Tuple<int, int> height = GetHeight();

      Console.WriteLine(height.Item1 + " - " + height.Item2);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Tuple<int, int> GetHeight()
    {
      return new Tuple<int, int>(2, 3);
    }
  }
```

**OUTPUT:**

`2 - 3`

Answer (score 2):

Also you could use `out` parameters:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int i, j;
  GetHeight(out i, out j);
}

public static void GetHeight(out int i1, out int i2)
{
  i1 = 1;
  i2 = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a int array.Or another way is to create class.

Comment: an array is definitely a bad way here - that's pretty allocatey *and* the semantic meaning of each value is unclear; creating a *class* would also be relatively allocatey, but... a `readonly struct` would be fine

Comment: Its not bad but its not needed in current question.

Comment: I'd rather have a class of strongly typed values that mean something rather than guessing how many are in the array and what their values represent

Comment: You can make a list too.

Comment: @VukUskokovic that (list) has all the problems that arrays have, plus an extra object and layer of abstraction; making it a list just *exacerbates* the problem unless we are semantically *returning a list of something*

Comment: My bad its not bad way i ment there are easier ways.

Comment: @MarcGravell i agree but you can make a list of how many integers he wants not return just 2 thats how i got the question.

Comment: @VukUskokovic fair enough - the question is unclear and ambiguous; if the intent is essentially an arbitray `List<double> GetHeights()` method, then yes: this would be a **good** solution (it shows how important clear context is, which is a problem of the question, not your answer)

Comment: @VukUskokovic I've added a comment/query to the question

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you.