# How can I get the output of a method that returns a triple and put it into three variables?

Tags: c#

I have this function call:

```
 GetLabels(phraseSources[seq].Kanji.Trim(), phraseSources[seq].Kana.Trim());
```

It returns (string, string,string)

How can I put this into three variables, named for example a, b & c?

Comment: `var (a, b, c) = GetLabels(...);`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways to do so,
first, you can use

Use [.NET 4.0+'s Tuple:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/return-multiple-values-to-a-method-caller)

For Example:

```
public Tuple<int, int> GetMultipleValue()
{
     return Tuple.Create(1,2);
}
```

Tuples with two values have Item1 and Item2 as properties.

or in [C# 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) you can do this:

```
(string firstName, string lastName) GetName(string myParameter)
    {
        var firstName = myParameter;
        var lastName = myParameter + " something";
        return (firstName, lastName);
    }

    void DoSomethingWithNames()
    {
        var (firstName, lastName) = GetName("myname");

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1 (Pass by Reference)**

As C# is like C language, it supports references. You can create 3 strings in main (or wherever you call this function) and pass their references:

```
string a, b, c;
GetLabels(phraseSources[seq].Kanji.Trim(), phraseSources[seq].Kana.Trim(), ref a, ref, b, ref c);
```

You also have to change function, so that it receives those three variables. Then assign those references needed values, instead of `return`.

**Method 2 (Return Object)**

You also can create an object in function (for ex.: array, tuple etc.) and return it. After function call, disassemble that object and store needed values inside of your strings.

I would recommend you to use first method, as it is more memory efficient (otherwise, you create new object and its copy)

**Method 3** (Return multiple objects in C#7) (solution by @phalanx)

```
(string firstName, string lastName) GetName(string myParameter)
    {
        var firstName = myParameter;
        var lastName = myParameter + " something";
        return (firstName, lastName);
    }

void DoSomethingWithNames()
{
    var (firstName, lastName) = GetName("myname");
}
```

I just feeled that combining all solutions togehter is better idea))