# How to return values from multiple variable from ReadFirstOrDefaultAsync in c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dapper

Here is my method. I want to return the value of the variables and assign it to the model.

How to return values from the variables item1 and item2?

```
public async Task <(int, int)> GetCount(int CustId, string userId)
{
    _log.Info($"Enter- GetCount");
    const string query = @" Select count(*) from Products
                            Select count(*) from Units";
    using (IDbConnection myConnection = 
    _getConnection.GetConnection(GetConnectionStringFromDict(userId)))
    {
        _log.Info($"Exit- GetCount");
        using (var multi = await myConnection.QueryMultipleAsync(query, new { CustId 
        }).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            var item1 = multi.ReadFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>();
            var item2 = multi.ReadFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>();
        }
    }
    using (IDbConnection myConnection = 
    _getConnection.GetConnection(GetConnectionStringFromDict(userId)))
    {
        _log.Info($"Exit- GetCount");
        return (await myConnection.QueryAsync<(int, int)>(query, new { CustId 
        }).ConfigureAwait(false)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to return `item1` and `item2` as a tuple, you can use `return (item1, item2)`. It's unclear what would happen to your existing `return` in this case though!

Comment: Unrelated: You don't seem to use `CustId` in your queries? Is that right?

Comment: From a readability standpoint: Yes you can return a Tuple. But I'd actually suggest returning a ResultClass (or Struct or since recently: Record), so you can have named Properties "ProductsCount" and "UnitsCount" ... but that's quite opinionated.

Comment: @Fildor : I have missed adding based on custID, But Im not getting how to return values from item1 and item2

Comment: @canton7:  return (item1, item2) I have tried this, but no luck.

Comment: Have a look at @JohnathanBarclays's answer. I think he's on to something.

Comment: @SuvarnaS Post what you tried, and what makes you think you had "no luck". Unfortunately the batteries in my mind-reading device are flat today, so you'll have to do the hard work and actually tell me what's wrong :)

Comment: ^^ What part are struggling with? To return a Tuple or that the returned tuple doesn't have the desired values? Or both?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return multiple values to a method caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/return-multiple-values-to-a-method-caller)

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReadFirstOrDefaultAsync` will return the product count twice.

You need to read the results as a collection, which can be converted into a tuple:

```
public async Task <(int, int)> GetCount(int CustId, string userId)
{
    _log.Info($"Enter- GetCount");
    const string query = @" Select count(*) from Products
                            Select count(*) from Units";
    using (IDbConnection myConnection = _getConnection
        .GetConnection(GetConnectionStringFromDict(userId)))
    {
        _log.Info($"Exit- GetCount");
        using (var multi = await myConnection.QueryMultipleAsync(query, new { CustId })
            .ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            var items = await multi.ReadAsync<int>();
            return (items.First(), items.Last());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the values of both variables here. But not getting how to return the values.                                                                                                
                    var item = multi.ReadFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>();
                    var item1 = multi.ReadFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>();

Comment: @SuvarnaS _"But not getting how to return the values."_ It's literally part of the answer: `return (items.First(), items.Last());` What exactly is it you don't get about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Tuple to return multiple items from a function call.

```
public async Task<Tuple<int, int>> GetCount(int CustId, string userId) {
  ...
  return new Tuple<int, int>(item1, item2);
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: This will give me error saying Cannot Implicitly convert type Systm.Tuple<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>, <System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>> to System.Tuple<(int,int)>.

Comment: Then you mixed up tuple and task :P It should be `Task<Tuple<int, int>>` not `Tuple<Task<int>, Task<int>>`.

Comment: I have'nt mixed up... I added as Jason provided., I am getting error.

Comment: Sorry about that Suvarna, I updated the answer.  This at least compiles on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can return ValueTuples by just putting them in parentheses.

```cs
static (int, int) test()
{
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    return (a, b);
}
```

Comment: @SuvarnaS "No Luck" is _not_ enough a description for failure. What makes you think you had "no luck"? A compiler error? Runtime Exception? Wrong results?