# How to return multiple values without using "out" keyword?

Tags: c#, xamarin

For example I want to return multiple value from this function

```
public int,int Sum(int a,int b) 
{
   return (a,b);
}
```

Comment: One way would be to return a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) e.g. `public (int, int) Sum(int a, int b)`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748062/return-multiple-values-to-a-method-caller

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, you notice that we have defined a function, calculated the minimum and maximum values and then returned a Tuple of type<int,int> back to the calling method. This lets the compiler know that a tuple having 2 integer values is being returned back.

```
public Tuple<int,int> MultipleReturnsFromSUM(int a, int b)  
{  
    int min, max;  
    if (a > b)  
    {  
        max = a;  
        min = b;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        max = b;  
        min = a;  
    }  
    return new Tuple<int, int>(min, max);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case just use value tuple.

```
public (int,int) Sum(int a,int b) 
{
   return (a,b);
}
```

Comment: When should i use Tupple?

Comment: @pradeepshukla Never. Or only in case you are using below C# 7.0. Value tuple is an improved version of Tuple.