# How would I implicitly call a method after having explicitly called another specific type of method

Tags: web-services, design-patterns

Lets say I have a bunch of methods in a class which call a Webservice and, as a result, I need to check the "response" of the Webservice each time one of these methods is called.
But I don't want to do something like this:

```
MethodA() // non web service related method

MethodB() // Web service calling method

if _response == OK then 
   MethodC()
```

In essence I want to get the check without explicitly calling it.

So I would actually like to be doing something like this:

```
MethodA()
MethodB() //If this fails, don't continue 
MethodC()
```

And I would bomb out of the calling sequence with the  internal _response variable updated and execution stopping.

As I am typing I am thinking that each of the Methods would need to do the check themselves or at least call something which does this check before doing their thang.

Am I overcomplicating things here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception in `MethodB()` and handle it in upper level. This way, if exception is thrown inside `MethodB()`, `MethodC()` won't get called.

Comment: I was kind of hoping for something a little less heavyweight and elegant than using exceptions.  AFAIK Exception handling shouldn't be used to control the flow of a program.

Comment: I can only direct you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253314/exceptions-or-error-codes, there's lot of discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had a bit more of a detailed looked at application blocks.  Perhaps using the exception or policy injection application blocks might have some legs.