# when using try/except with python and calling functions and trying to catch function errors

Tags: python

In Python, can I use try and except when calling functions from my core function, and error checking that the called functions are succeeding? Is this a good way to structure your script with the core function calling functions and sandwiching them in try/except statements to manage errors? If the called functions throw an error or a False, will the try in the core function manage that?

```
def core_function():

    try:
        function_a()
    except_Exception as e:
        print(e)

    try:
        function_b()
    except Exception as E:
        print(e)


def function_a()
    #this will error
    print 1 + 'a'
    return True

def function_b()
    print 1 + 1
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the called functions throw an error or a False, will the try in the core function manage that

There are basically two ways a function can report an error. By returning something that indicates an error or by [raise](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)ing an exception. `try catch` block in Python handles the latter. You can do something like that.

```
def core_function():

    try:
        if function_a() == False:
            raise Exception('function_a failed')
        if function_b() == False:
            raise Exception('function_b failed')

    except Exception as E:
        print(e)
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253314/conventions-for-exceptions-or-error-codes) for `Conventions for error reporting: Exceptions vs returning error codes`

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. Would you sandwich all your function calls from the core function inside a try catch block as standard practice, or just the risky ones?

Comment: I would prefer all be part of the `try catch` block.

Comment: I have read that try blocks should be kept simple and not hold multiple things. and this workflow does seem to violate that, but I do like the idea of working this way.

Comment: It's just safe to put function in try catch if they might throw an error. Using the above approach have one benefit of having error handling code at a single place which basically help with readability.